# Clicking an href to our Github oAuth endpoint works, but an AJAX request to same endpoint gives a CORS error?

Tags: ajax, github, oauth, cors, passport.js

We are trying to implement Github oAuth in our app using Passport.js.  If the user hits the endpoint by clicking an anchor tag/href, it works fine, but if we use a click handler to initiate an ajax request instead, we receive a CORS error from the Github server. Why?

Server side code:

```
app.get('/auth/github',
  passport.authenticate('github', { scope: [ 'user:email' ] }));

app.get('/auth/github/callback',
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
   function(req, res) {
    console.log('Github authentication successful!');
    res.redirect('/');
 });
```

Client side code (we are using React):

--> Works:

```
<a href='/auth/github'>Contact</a>;
```

--> Does Not Work - CORS error:

```
handleContactAuth(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/auth/github',
    method: 'GET',
    success: data => console.log( 'Contact Auth response: ', data),
    error: err => console.log( 'Error connecting to GitHub.', err)
  });
}
```

NOTE: This is a click handler on the React component and is functioning    fine, as the ajax request is being triggered. I'm aware we're not handling the response currently, apart from just a `console.log`.

--> CORS Error we see on the Client side when using AJAX method instead of href:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?      response_type=code&redirect_uri=ht…auth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&scope=user%3Aemail&client_id=our_client_code. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Any ideas? Would appreciate any insights - many thanks.

Comment: ...I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

CORS error is not an error returned by the server, but one triggered by the browser if the response doesn't contain HTTP headers signaling that cross-origin requests are allowed. The endpoint you are hitting obviously isn't designed to be accessed like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that at least in Google Chrome XMLHttpRequest object is restricted to same origin policy. So you may need to stick to using an anchor tag.

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

Link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr